# connecting value to another modal

Tags: php, html

I'm using double bootstrap modal from [Open modal inside a Modal](http://jschr.github.io/bootstrap-modal/)

my sample code [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/62177/)

I want to give `hiddenvalue` to my buttons and call it in the another modal  but I'm not using form so I can't use `hiddenvalue=""`

```
   <button data-toggle="modal" **value="Johndoeinfo"** href="#stack2">John Doe</button>
   <button data-toggle="modal" **value="Alexgrayinfo"** href="#stack2">alex gray</button>
```

i want my modal 2 be like

```
<div id="stack2">
<?php
$value = button value;
echo $value; 
?>
</div>
```

Is that possible with PHP?

Comment: _...is that possible with php ?_ Try and find out

Comment: @B001ᛦ what do you mean ? i've been searching for 1 hour

Comment: _searching for 1 hour..._ 1 hour? you just need less than 5 mins to run the code and to see what happens...

Answer (score 1):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

      </head>
      <body>
<!--    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" name="okBtn" value="<?= $arrData ?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button> -->

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" name="okBtn" value="myValue" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">

            <p><?php echo "<script>document.getElementsByName('okBtn')[0].value;</script>"; ?></p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" id="okBtn" value="myValue" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$btns->getElementById("okBtn");
foreach ($btns as $btn) {
    foreach ($btn->attributes as $attr) {
      $name = $attr->nodeName;
      $value = $attr->nodeValue;
      echo "Attribute '$name' :: '$value'<br />";
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: idon't want to use js but.. can this work with <a> not button ?